# Wait till thread finishes

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, multiprocessing

Main Class:

```
producer p = new producer();
food me = new food();
me.eat(times,p);
....>Rest of Code<.......
```

Other classes:

```
class food {

    public int times;
    public int food;
    public boolean canget=false;
    boolean done=false;



   void eat(int times,producer p){

       this.times = times;
       p.produce(this);
       consumer pe = new consumer();
       pe.consume(this);


   }

    synchronized void add(int n){
        while(canget) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Something nasty happened");
            }
        }

        this.food = n;
        System.out.println("Produced food '"+n+"'");
        canget = true;
        notify();
    }
    synchronized int get(){
        while (!canget){
            try{
                wait();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Something Nasty happened");
            }
        }
        canget = false;
        notify();
        System.out.println("Eaten food '"+this.food+"'");
        return this.food;
    }

}

class producer implements Runnable{
    int times;
    food f;
    boolean done;

    boolean done(Thread t) {
        return done;
    }

    void produce(food F){
        times=F.times;
        f=F;
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();



        }


    public void run() {
        while(this.times-- > 0){
            f.add(times);

        }

    }
}

class consumer implements Runnable{

    int times;
    food f;

    void consume(food F){
        times=F.times;
        f=F;
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while(this.times-- > 0){
            f.get();
        }
    }
}
```

After this statement:

```
me.eat(times,p);
```

The rest of code is running but I want that after the threads run by `food`, `producer` and `consumer` finished. How can I do this?

Comment: If you only want to continue after production has completed, why is `produce` starting a new thread at all? (Note that your code would be easier to read if you followed normal Java naming conventions...)

Comment: You will need to keep a reference to your threads so that you can access them, then call "join" on each one. Your main thread will then "join" the execution of that thread. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29

Comment: @Bret I am new here, please telll how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a CountDownLatch to allow the producer and consumer to signal when they are done, and wait for that signal in your main code.

Main code :

```
int times = 3;

CountDownLatch completion = new CountDownLatch(2);

producer p = new producer(completion);
food me = new food(completion);
me.eat(times, p);


try {
    completion.await();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("Done");
```

Updated classes :

```
class food {

    public int times;
    public int food;
    public boolean canget = false;
    private CountDownLatch completion;

    public food(CountDownLatch completion) {
        this.completion = completion;
    }

    void eat(int times, producer p) {
        this.times = times;
        p.produce(this);
        consumer pe = new consumer(completion);
        pe.consume(this);
    }

    synchronized void add(int n) {
        while (canget) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Something nasty happened");
            }
        }

        this.food = n;
        System.out.println("Produced food '" + n + "'");
        canget = true;
        notify();
    }

    synchronized int get() {
        while (!canget) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Something Nasty happened");
            }
        }
        canget = false;
        notify();
        System.out.println("Eaten food '" + this.food + "'");
        return this.food;
    }

}

class producer implements Runnable {
    int times;
    food f;
    boolean done;
    private CountDownLatch completion;

    public producer(CountDownLatch completion) {
        this.completion = completion;
    }

    void produce(food F) {
        times = F.times;
        f = F;
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }


    public void run() {
        while (this.times-- > 0) {
            f.add(times);
        }
        completion.countDown();
    }
}

class consumer implements Runnable {

    int times;
    food f;
    private CountDownLatch completion;

    public consumer(CountDownLatch completion) {
        this.completion = completion;
    }

    void consume(food F) {
        times = F.times;
        f = F;
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (this.times-- > 0) {
            f.get();
        }
        completion.countDown();
    }
}
```